# Can i add wpf Customcontrol.cs in wpf class library project

Tags: wpf

i created cusomcontrol in wpf which comes in wpf customcontrol library project . But i want to use it in wpf class library .Can i use this resource file and .cs file in in wpf class library .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference to your `custom control` library. So your `WPF class library` will have a reference to your `custom control library`. And you probably have to add some WPF specific DLL's (PresentationCore.dll, PresentationFramework.dll,...).
To add a reference, you can read [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294670.aspx).